# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I need some help with my code. I am working on datetime.datetime objects to calculating between `19:00` and `22:15`. I want to calculating the datetime objects and then multiply by the value `11.4`.

When I try this:

```
program_time = program_stop_time - program_start_time
program_duration = program_time * 11.4
```

I will get an error: **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'**

Here it is the input for the variables:

program_start_time:

```
2018-05-01 19:00:00
```

program_stop_time:

[python]
2018-05-01 22:15:00
[/python]

Here is the return output when I calculating:

```
3:15:00
```

Here is the code:

```
start_time = time.strptime('20180501190000', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
program_start_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(start_time))
stop_time = time.strptime('20180501221500', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
program_stop_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(stop_time))

program_duration = program_stop_time - program_start_time
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
3591
```

Can you please show me an example how I can use the correct way to solve the problem to allow me to calculate the datetime objects and then multiply by the value to get the return output I want??

Comment: have you tried: `print(program_duration.total_seconds() * 11.4)`

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have tried it and it gave me the wrong output: `133380.0`. The output I want is `3591` not `133380.0`.

Comment: @miindlek the python version I am using is 2.6v.

Comment: any idea???????????